# Videos have audio on right channel only, how can I make it sound through both channels?

Tags: audio, video

I've downloaded m4v videos (legally if you should ask*) and played them with Quicktime, VLC and MplayerX.

They have the audio only in the right channel, is there a way I can equalize the output so I hear it through both channels?

I've tried equalizing from Audio Preferences but it obviously just decreases the volume of one channel and increases the other, but doesn't move the output from one channel to the other.

* http://www.atheist-experience.com/videocast.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Universal Access preferences to play the same audio in both channels:

[image]